# has_and_belongs_to_many - getting data from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails app uses three tables: A, B, C. A table is related to table C through table B. Relation is many-to-many. Also table B contains some extra fields like rel_date, etc. Relation between tables works fine, but I do not know how to get B table extra fields data.Because if I make A.Cs, I only get C table elements that are related to table A. Don't know how to get all fields that are in table B?

Any ideas?

Comment: is it `has_many :through` or `has_and_belongs_to_many`?  It needs to be `has_many :through` if you want to access the join as a proper model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails has a `has_many ... through` association type that does what you're after:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_dishes
  has_many :dishes, through: restaurant_dishes
end

class RestaurantDish < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :restaurant
 belongs_to :dish

 # Other attributes, e.g. price
end

class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_dishes
  has_many :restaurants, through: restaurant_dishes
end
```

This allows you to do things like `@restaurant.restaurant_dishes.where(dish: @dish)` to access the middle table, but still use the shortcut `@restaurant.dishes` if you're not interested in the middle table.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association for more info

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_b
  has_many :model_c, through: :model_b
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_a
  has_many :model_b
end

class ModelC < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_b
  has_many :model_a, through: :model_b
end
```

Now you can access `C` from `A` and vice-versa, as you did before, but also access `B` from both too.